# How to determine video width and height on Android

Tags: android, video, media-player, android-videoview

I have a video file and I want to get width and height of video. I don't want to play it, just to get size.
I've tried to use MediaPlayer:

```
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
mp.setDataSource(uriString);
mp.prepare();
int width = mp.getVideoWidth();
int height = mp.getVideoHeight();
```

but it returns 0 for width and height, because VideoSizeChangedEvent didn't fire yet.
How can I get width and height of video?

UPD: I need API version 7

Answer (score 46):

This works in API level 10 and up:

```
MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
retriever.setDataSource("/path/to/video.mp4");
int width = Integer.valueOf(retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_WIDTH));
int height = Integer.valueOf(retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_HEIGHT));
retriever.release();
```

Comment: @TigranSarkisian does the app crash in android 6.0?

Comment: It works after API 10. But it throws `IllegalArgumentException` if path is invalid or file doesn't exist.

Comment: Works on android 7.1

Comment: Should use the `parseInt()` method instead of `valueOf`. Anyway you saved my day !

Comment: retriever.setDataSource doesn't work

Answer (score 23):

In some cases, we are unable to read the metadata. To ensure that we get the width and height, it is best to create a `Bitmap` using `MediaMetadataRetriever`, then get the width and height from the created `Bitmap`, as shown below:

```
public int getVideoWidthOrHeight(File file, String widthOrHeight) {
    MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = null;
    Bitmap bmp = null;
    FileInputStream inputStream = null;
    int mWidthHeight = 0;                                                                                                                
    try {
        retriever = new  MediaMetadataRetriever();
        inputStream = new FileInputStream(file.getAbsolutePath());
        retriever.setDataSource(inputStream.getFD());
        bmp = retriever.getFrameAtTime();
        if (widthOrHeight.equals("width")){
            mWidthHeight = bmp.getWidth();
        }else {
            mWidthHeight = bmp.getHeight();
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally{
       if (retriever != null){
           retriever.release()
       }if (inputStream != null){
           inputStream.close()
       }
    }  
    return mWidthHeight;
}
```

You can call the above method like this:

```
// Get the video width
int mVideoWidth = getVideoWidthOrHeight(someFile, "width");
// Get the video height
int mVideoHeight = getVideoWidthOrHeight(someFile, "height");
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to write, that I need API verion 7, so there is no MediaMetadataRetriever

Comment: Thanks for that code, however I can't figure out how to get the appropriate string for a file in the res/raw folder of my project, any suggestions?

Answer (score 14):

This worked for me

```
videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(final MediaPlayer mp) {
                int width = mp.getVideoWidth();
                int height = mp.getVideoHeight();
            }
        });
```

Comment: when getting height and width of videos from some of the url application gets hang and also if we cannot get height and width from video app gets hang.

Comment: Only thing that works for me - that MediaMetadataRetriever doesn't seem to know much about video sizes...

Answer (score 7):

API level 7 solution:

```
// get video dimensions
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
        try {
            mp.setDataSource(filename);
            mp.prepare();
            mp.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(new OnVideoSizeChangedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onVideoSizeChanged(MediaPlayer mp, int width, int height) {

                    int orient = -1;

                    if(width < height)
                        orient = 1;
                    else
                        orient = 0;

                }
            });
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: when getting height and width of videos from some of the url application gets hang and also if we cannot get height and width from video app gets hang.

Answer (score 1):

This [set of utilities](https://github.com/sokolyaka/sizes) to work with the Size abstraction in Android.

It contains an class [SizeFromVideoFile.java](https://github.com/sokolyaka/sizes/blob/master/androidsizes/src/main/java/com/sokolov/androidsizes/SizeFromVideoFile.java)
You can use it like this:

```
ISize size = new SizeFromVideoFile(videoFilePath);
size.width();
size.hight();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private static final Uri MOVIE_URI = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
private static final String[] MOVIE_PJT = new String[] {
        MediaStore.Video.Media._ID, MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA,
        MediaStore.Video.Media.TITLE, MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_TAKEN,
        MediaStore.Video.Media.MIME_TYPE, MediaStore.Video.Media.DURATION,
        MediaStore.Video.Media.SIZE, MediaStore.Video.Media.RESOLUTION };
```

try this to query from system content provider. It will return some useful info of the Videos(local files)

Comment: At least some of the time, `RESOLUTION` is null. (I'm not yet sure when it's non-null, but I ran into this question looking for a way to get resolution (on Gingerbread and up, alas) when `RESOLUTION` is not available.

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin Version

```
data class VideoSize(val width: Int, val height: Int)
```

Extention Function

```
fun Uri.getVideoSize(): VideoSize {
        val retriever = MediaMetadataRetriever()
        retriever.setDataSource(appContext, this)
        val width =
            retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_WIDTH)?.toInt() ?: 0
        val height =
            retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_HEIGHT)?.toInt() ?: 0
        retriever.release()
        return VideoSize(width, height)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

kotlin version used in my app referring to user493244's answer

```
     /**
     * determine video width and height
     *
     *
     * Refer to [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9077436/how-to-determine-video-width-and-height-on-android)
     * answer of  [user493244](https://stackoverflow.com/users/493244/user493244)
     *
     * @param file string with file pathname to use
     * @param widthOrHeight string with size required (width or height)
     * @return mWidthHeight int with video width or height
     */
    fun getVideoWidthOrHeight(file: String?, widthOrHeight: String): Int {
        var retriever: MediaMetadataRetriever? = null
        val bmp: Bitmap?
        //
        var mWidthHeight = 0
        try {
            retriever = MediaMetadataRetriever()
            //
            retriever.setDataSource(file)
            bmp = retriever.frameAtTime
            mWidthHeight = if (widthOrHeight == getString(R.string.width)) {
                bmp!!.width
            } else {
                bmp!!.height
            }
        } catch (e: RuntimeException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        } finally {
            if (retriever != null) {
                try {
                    retriever.release()
                } catch (e: IOException) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
            }
        }
        return mWidthHeight
    }
```